# calendar not rendered correctly in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar

My page uses the [FullCalendar jQuery plugin](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) to shows a monthly event calendar. If events occur on the same day, a very small space is left between them when the calendar is viewed in Firefox or IE, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

On the other hand, if the same page is viewed in Chrome, a large (unwanted) space is shown between these events:

[image]

How can I eliminate this empty space when the page is viewed in Chrome?

### Update

I removed all bootstrap styles from the app and the problem no longer occurs, so I guess there's some bootrap CSS rule(s) which are being applied to the rendering of the calendar in Chrome only. Now I just need to figure out which rule(s)....

Comment: You have asked this before, and as yet no code shown. Quick look: seems like you have munged the markup (in `eventRender`?), because it does not seem to have the familiar `fc-event-head`, `fc-event-content`, etc...

Comment: @MaxD I don't think there's any problem with the markup per se, because that's generated by the plugin itself. Also see my update above.

Comment: I don't suppose you could use the unminified .js files for the FullCalendar jQuery plugin at http://festivals.ie/festival/calendar (strictly for the purpose of debugging this)? Also, the first `td` in the table for the calendar (the one representing 12/31/2012) has a `div` (child of `div.fc-day-content`) that is calculated at `170px` tall in Chrome, where as in Firefox it's calculated at `65px` tall. I suspect the miscalculation of the top of the `a.fc-event` may have to do with that.

Comment: @Don I am not able to see the screen shot? is there any issue in the upload or I have not privilege, I am clueless

Comment: @Mehavel I have no idea why you can't see the screenshot

Comment: @Mehavel Here's the direct links to the screenshots, if it helps. 1) http://i.stack.imgur.com/s5t8Y.png  2) http://i.stack.imgur.com/jGfJn.png

Comment: It's completely unacceptable to post a question containing nothing but off-site links, and say "fix this". That is now what Stack Overflow is for, regardless of your bounty. The question needs to be fully self-contained and answerable without opening any external links.

Comment: Don, we really can't help you without seeing the relevant code, within the question. The screen shots show us what happens, not why. I'm refunding the bounty on this and closing it out.

Comment: @TimPost fair enough, the code is on the webpage that I linked to, I didn't see much point in reproducing it here. But I'll do that in future if that's what the rules dictate

Comment: @Don The page you linked to is the plugin home page, or did I miss something? I was speaking specifically to the implementation of it that you're having difficulty with.

Comment: @TimPost sorry, looks like I screwed up somewhere. I meant to include a link to the page that has the problem (which would allow people to see the code), but it seems that I forgot to include the link. Obviously I don't expect people to help with problems if they've no access to the code. Apologies one and all. Feel free to delete this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Fixed

Strangely, the layout problem was caused by this CSS rule

```
    a {
        -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s !important;
        -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s !important;
        -o-transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s !important;
        transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s !important;
    }
```

I changed it to:

```
    a {
        -webkit-transition: none !important;
        -moz-transition: none !important;
        -o-transition: none !important;
        transition: none !important;
    }
```

and the problem is resolved

Answer (score 1):

One thing is for certain, it somehow involves whatever is setting the code for the inline `top` positioning on the wrapping `a` element. Both Firefox and Chrome are setting the first element to `top: 52px` but the second element is being placed differently, with Firefox setting it to `top: 95px` and Chrome to `top: 137px`.

This top positioning difference is likely because of the `height` difference being set on the `div` nested inside the `div` with class `fc-day-content`. The `height` of that `div` is `170px` in Chrome, but `65px` in Firefox. Now, the items in question are actually overlaid onto the `fc-day-content` structure, they are not direct children of it. But apparently the code must read the height of that structure somehow to calculate where to place the items in relation to the "day" they are overlaying. So the taller height of the `div` inside `fc-day-content` in Chrome may be affecting it (or the reverse, the placement of the `a` is affecting the `height` of the `fc-day-content` nesting).

I've not yet tracked down the code that is placing those items positions.

Comment: I noticed the same. I wonder if setting an initial CSS `height:0px; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px;` on `fc-day-content` would make a difference. A jQuery code segment I used a few weeks ago needed the initial height to be zeroed out to properly compensate for the height of dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin calculates the position of the calendar-event wrong.
I would suggest initializing the calender on `load event` instead of `ready`.
So replace the

```
$(document).ready(function() {.....
```

part with

```
$(window).load(function() {.....
```

and see if any progress.

Additional feedback would be helpful in the research, BR.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but unfortunately it made no difference

Answer (score 0):

You should try using relative positioning: for a elements like so

```
position: relative;
width: 195px;
margin-top: 30px;
float: left;
```