# How can I reproduce website crash on iOS 6.1

Tags: ios, safari, ios6.1

I received a bug report that [this website](http://festivals.ie/) crashes when viewed on iOS 6.1, though I guess it's the browser version that comes with iOS 6.1 that's more relevant than the OS itself. I don't own any iOS devices, so I'm not sure how I can reproduce/investigate the issue.

Does anyone have a suggestion for how I might reproduce this issue on Windows/Ubunutu? I tried http://www.browserstack.com/ but the latest version they offer is iOS 6.0.

In the unlikely event that anyone has an idea why the crash is happening, please let me know. There is an embedded YouTube video on the homepage, and I've heard that flash and iOS are uneasy bedfellows, so I'm wondering if this could be the cause?

Comment: You can have Safari installed on machine and enable developer mode on this. After this try opening the website with user-agent ios 6.1 (under Develop tab that appears after enabling developer mode)

Comment: Forget flash. If you did it right you didn't actually put the flash in the website but instead a piece of code that detects the browser and the device to select what to show. Try what saury said or go with the greater explanation from @nizx which is the correct way to do.

Comment: The problem seems to be fixed now (not crashing anymore, as opposed to 10 minutes ago). If you have found the reason for it, please report the bug to Apple. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by the commented-out CSS properties below

```
html {
  background: url(../images/responsive/bg.svg) no-repeat center center fixed;

/* 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
*/

  outline: 0!important;
}
```

After removing these properties, the problem no longer occurs

Comment: That is so strange, and certainly a bug. I'm having a similar issue where Safari (both mobile and desktop) are crashing when I load my site. Wonder if it has to do with commented styles. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987787/my-website-crashes-safari-both-desktop-and-ios-consistently

Comment: Whoa - so I disabled my whole stylesheet and the site no longer crashes Safari. However, I know the issue wasn't commented out styles, because I'm using a minified css file without any comments in it. So something in the regular style declarations is actually crashing Safari. This must be a Safari bug.

Comment: @JoelGlovier I found which rule was responsible by brute force. Specifically, remove half the styles. If the error still occurs, you know the problem is in the remaining styles, otherwise the problem is in the removed styles. Include whichever half contains the error, then remove half of this. Repeat this process until you identify the rule responsible. Not much fun, but it worked for me (eventually)

Comment: So I ended up narrowing down my problem to the transition rule, specially using the "all" transition scope was crashing it, and when I changed "all" to "color" (since that's all I really needed to transition) it stopped crashing the browser.

Comment: I also had problems with `transition` rules, though in my case it was causing problems in Chrome http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468781/calendar-not-rendered-correctly-in-chrome

Answer (score 6):

## Update

I was able to reproduce the issue, and get this info from the console logs:

> Feb 14 12:45:54 Aaron-Bragers-iPhone MobileSafari[45279] :
> CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix. Feb 14 12:45:56
> Aaron-Bragers-iPhone MobileSafari[45279] :
> CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix. Feb 14 12:45:56
> Aaron-Bragers-iPhone MobileSafari[45279] :
> CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix. Feb 14 12:45:57
> Aaron-Bragers-iPhone MobileSafari[45279] :
> CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix. Feb 14 12:45:59
> Aaron-Bragers-iPhone ReportCrash[46048] : Not saving Jetsam
> log because no data from the kernel. Feb 14 12:45:59
> Aaron-Bragers-iPhone UserEventAgent[13] : jetsam: kernel
> termination snapshot being created Feb 14 12:45:59
> Aaron-Bragers-iPhone MobileSafari[45279] :
> CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix. Feb 14 12:46:04
> Aaron-Bragers-iPhone MobileSafari[45279] :
> CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix. Feb 14 12:46:04
> Aaron-Bragers-iPhone MobileSafari[45279] :
> CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix. Feb 14 12:46:05
> Aaron-Bragers-iPhone MobileSafari[45279] :
> CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix. Feb 14 12:46:06
> Aaron-Bragers-iPhone MobileSafari[45279] :
> CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix.

... followed by lots of memory warnings.

Your website is causing a memory leak, so iOS is shutting Safari down.  Looks like you'll have to [follow these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121807/console-error-cgaffinetransforminvert-singular-matrix-in-uiwebview) to debug it.

---

## Windows

There isn't much you can do to try to reproduce it in Windows.  The only option is to [download Safari 5 for Windows](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1531), which might produce similar errors.

However, this doesn't use the same build of WebKit as Mobile Safari (Safari for Windows is much older) so you'll probably need to borrow a friend's Mac and follow along:

## Mac

### 1. Test your website in the iOS Simulator

**Get Xcode**

If you don't already have it, [download Xcode from the Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12).

**Make a blank project**

File -> New Project.  Select Single View application (or any other iOS application, it doesn't matter).  Press Next.  Pick any project name (doesn't matter).  Press next, then specify some location, and press Create.

**Run the project**

Press the play button in the upper left corner, or press Command-R, or select Run from the Product menu.

The app should launch in the simulator.

**Switch to Safari**

Press the home button (or command-shift-H).  Then tap Safari, and navigate to your website.

### 2. Log output.

Open up Terminal, and run `tail -f /var/log/system.log | egrep 'MobileSafari'`.  This will show you all of Mobile Safari's logs.  (You can remove the `egrep` to see *all* logs, in case the crash is outside of Safari.)

## 2. Reproduce the issue

I was unable to make iOS or Safari crash on your site, but you'll need to do so to debug the issue.

## 3. Check the simulator's console logs for details

Switch back to Terminal and review the logs for info about what might have caused the crash.

Comment: thanks a lot, unfortunately neither myself nor any of my friends own macs

Answer (score 6):

I was able to reproduce the issue on my iPhone 3GS iOS 6.1 it crashes instantly without any action on the page. There's no error on the Web Inspector. When using iOS Simulator, it does Not crash but it show `MobileSafari[11079]: CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix.` on device log.

If I scroll the page without interacting with none of the elements, the error `singular matrix` repeat on console, even if I scroll 1 by pixel.

[image]

Profiling many times, on iOS Simulator I don't see any javascript memory leak. So I would guess that this is rendering related.

So I removed the stylesheet `http://festivals.ie/static/mNga2i69LFf9ezK2IBanFA9rPb7jjsGzC6PNOP5MjO1.css` to check, and the matrix errors stopped. So that's confirm my concern.

Next we need to be able to separate, what is causing this.

I profiled the page, and scrolled the page, wait for the `singular matrix` error, and stopped the profiling. This is what I got:

[image]

A redraw area of 320 by 75 pixels, that I would guess is the top header.
[image]

So I removed the `<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top top-nav">` using the web inspector, and no more `singular matrix` errors.

[image]

I tried enabling and disabling every style that matches to the div, the only one that made any difference was `position: fixed`, but it may be something conflicting inside the fixed div.

[image]

I tried every element inside, and **I found that removing just the `<button>` fixed the issue.**

[image]
[image]

Now I think that you can track what is the problem of that button.

this is the css related to the button:

```
media="screen, projection"
mNga2i69LFf9ezK2IBanFA9rPb7jjsGzC6PNOP5MjO1.css:175
label, input, button, select, textarea {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 20px;
}

festivals.ie
media="screen, projection"
mNga2i69LFf9ezK2IBanFA9rPb7jjsGzC6PNOP5MjO1.css:21
button, input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"] {
cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: button;
}

festivals.ie
media="screen, projection"
mNga2i69LFf9ezK2IBanFA9rPb7jjsGzC6PNOP5MjO1.css:19
button, input {
    line-height: normal;
}

festivals.ie
media="screen, projection"
mNga2i69LFf9ezK2IBanFA9rPb7jjsGzC6PNOP5MjO1.css:18
button, input, select, textarea {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

festivals.ie
media="screen, projection"
mNga2i69LFf9ezK2IBanFA9rPb7jjsGzC6PNOP5MjO1.css:859
* {
    margin: 0;
}

festivals.ie
media="screen, projection"
mNga2i69LFf9ezK2IBanFA9rPb7jjsGzC6PNOP5MjO1.css:798
::selection {
    background: #4e87e1;
    color: #ffffff;
}

Base Style Rules
input[type="button"], input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"], input[type="file"]::-webkit-file-upload-button, button {
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: default;
    color: buttontext;
    padding: 0px 1em;
    border: 1px solid rgb(76, 76, 76);
    border-image: initial;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0078125);
    font: 11px Helvetica;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input, textarea, keygen, select, button, isindex {
    margin: 0em;
    color: initial;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: -webkit-auto;
}

button {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
}
```

I hope that this was useful because it took me a long time until here.

Comment: @Vitim.us very thorough; +1.  Once you find the offending code, you should submit a report on http://bugreport.apple.com, because CSS should not be able to crash the browser under any circumstances.

Comment: I removed the button, but the problem still occurs. I made sure to clear the iPhone browser cache after removing the button. So it looks like the button wasn't the (only) problem

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to check this on iOS device.
2. iOS don't support flash

I think it won't happen in the safari installed on Windows or other platforms. I think it is a specific issue related to iOS.

**Note:**

I got the crash in your site. When I used your site and clicked the forward, backward arrows 5 to 6 times. And after when I clicked the image it goes to a page **festivals.ie/festival/map** something like that and crashed.

**EDIT:**

Tested the same on the safari installed on my mac. No crash found in the above case. So I think it is a iOS specific crash. (I think related to memory or something like that).

Comment: The page at `festivals.ie/festival/map` shows a Google map, so there's no flash on that page. However it probably does use quite a lot of memory on the client-side, particularly when a lot of map markers are displayed

Answer (score 1):

You will need to either register as an Apple Developer to use the simulator and use the web inspector to debug.

You can try the following link for more information.

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow-tutorials/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari/